# Configure tomcat 7 in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

I'm trying to configure tomcat 7 with intellij 12 but with no success.

If I run the catalina.sh startup script from command line, tomcat starts properly and I can see tomcat homepage.

If I run tomcat from Intellij, I get the following stacktrace (from intellijs log-file):

```
2013-03-20 21:11:48,631 [1065007]  DEBUG - .util.AbstractConnectorCommand -  
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:668)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1442)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
```

..............

Looks like it cannot find any instance of tomcat.

I do not get any errors in the output log in intellij, and no errors when configuring tomcat in intellij.

Output-log:
/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run

```
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in                   
    production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/rana/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 482 ms
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 37 ms
Connected to server
Mar 20, 2013 9:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/manager
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: This occurred for me because I had an IP address that was not not resolving for a Receiver element in server.xml